# Copy argument vs Series.Copy()

Tags: python, pandas

```
y = pd.Series(x, copy=True,dtype=float)
z = pd.Series(x, copy=True)
a = pd.Series(x)
f = pd.Series.copy(x)
```

All the above expressions give the same output of x value and even after updating the x value the change is not reflecting.
So I need to know what is the use of copy as argument and the series.copy() and also how to copy x series to some other series such that any changes made in x is reflected back in the new series also.

If any thing is wrong or not possible please forgive me... I'm a newbie to Python and I'm asking these questions out of my curiosity...

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: What is `pd`? You might want to tag your post with more then just `python` to attract the right audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the source code of pandas `Series` we can see the following,

```
def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None,
             copy=False, fastpath=False):

    if not isinstance(data, SingleBlockManager):
        data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
    if copy:
        data = data.copy()
```

So you have passed `x` for the `data` argument, therefore, the line `data = data.copy()` makes a copy of `x`. This should be equivalent to doing,

```
g = pd.Series(x.copy())
```

This is subtly different to `pd.Series.copy(x)` which now makes a copy of the Series object itself, not the underlying `x`. Therefore, the underlying `x` might still be referenced by the new Series.

The idea of making a copy is that you be confident that any operations you perform on the `Series` do not change the original object `x`.